# Module to sell entries?

Tags: module, ecommerce, membrr

I have been looking for a way to sell EE entries.

I have come across Membrr, but I have seen quite a lot of negative feedback.

Does anyone know of any other modules that would allow this?

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying sell `entries` like ads and posts OR membership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know Membrr is the only way to do this - however, if you know PHP/CI, you could write a custom module to do this which ties in to any of the e-commerce platforms out there.

I did something similar a while ago which used Brilliant Retail and simply allowed for entries to be created and then 'paid' for which had the action of putting them live.

All I did was to add the 'entry_id' being paid for into the cart data and then using the br_order_create_after hook pulled this out and updated the status to 'live'.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already seen this but there is an answer to another question (here: [Recurring subscription for posting channel entries](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/recurring-subscription-for-posting-channel-entries?rq=1)). They came to the conclusion that Simple Commerce, Membrr or Carthrob could work. That question is similar but not exactly the same.